# Whats the value of &y[0] == &x.a?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

Got this piece of code from an homework assignment. I should figure out, what the value of `&y[0] == &x.a`. Btw sorry for not formatting properly, I tried my best.

So my approach was; `y[0] = 1`, and `&y[0]` means the address of `1`, which is `0` in the array?

`x.a` confused me the most. Does it mean element a of the struct x? So `x.a == 1` ? And its address would also be `0`? So the boolean would come out as `true(1)`, because `0 == 0`. But the solution says it's false, but why?

```
struct my_struct {
    int a;
    double b;
    int c; 
};
my_struct x = { 1, 2, 3 }; 
int y[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

I expected the output `1` but apparently it's `0`, but why?

Comment: `a` is not initialized. That might be why the solution returns false. The value of `a` is basically random.

Comment: `x` and `y` are two different objects, why do you expect them to be stored at the same adress? Is it the `&` that confuses you?

Comment: You're comparing addresses here, so comparing between two distinct variables will always return `false`.

Comment: Why would you expect the address of two different variables to be the same? Both the struct `x` and the array `y` are allocated on the stack, and therefore will each get their own stack memory.

Comment: Unless they are both members of a union, an instance of `my_struct` does not occupy any memory in common with any elements of an array of `int`.   So `&y[0] == &x.a` should compare false (i.e. 0).   The fact you use the same initialiser `{1, 2, 3}` for both is irrelevant - the compiler uses that data to initialise `x` and `y`, but that doesn't affect the locations of `x` (or of its members) or of `y` (or of its elements) in memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> &y[0] means the address of 1, which is 0 in the array

Almost, but not quite. The addresses given to you by the address-of operator are absolute values, not ones relative to the "container". So `&y[0]` is effectively the same as `y`, and `&x.a` is *effectively* the same as `&x`.

`y` is a value that can be converted to a pointer to the first element. This must and will be distinct (numerically) from `&x` which occupies a different part of memory.

```
| x.a | <- &x points here
| x.b |
| x.c |
| y[0]| <- y points here
| y[1]|
[ y[2]|
```

All of the above skims over the fact that those pointers might have different types. This matters to the compiler when checking the correctness of your code, but is ultimately discarded afterwards, as all addresses effectively become numerical values.

Comment: `&y[0]` compares equal to `y`, since `y` will be converted to a pointer equivalent to `&y[0]` in order to do the comparison.

Comment: @Walter Yeah, it's hard to answer this kind of question without being technically wrong. It's a fine line between oversimplification and explanations that are too complex. I've changed the `x` to `&x`, hope that's enough to clear that part. *Technically* `y` also doesn't explicitly point to anything until we force it to decay to a pointer...

Comment: What is not clear here: can one compare two different pointer types with `==`?

Comment: @Walter Both `&y[0]` and `&x.a` have type `int*`.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz indeed.

Comment: `&x` has the same *value* as `&x.a`, but they have different *type*

Answer (score 5):

This expression

```
&y[0] == &x.a
```

compares addresses (pointers) of two different objects. The first one belongs to the array `y` (that is `y[0]` is the first element of the array) while the second one belongs to an object of the type my_struct (`a` is a data member of the object `x`).

The objects occupy different extents of memory.

So the expression yields false that is the addresses of the different objects are not equal each other.

I can provide an example when comparing two different pointers (that is pointers of different types) yields true.

Consider the following example

```
struct my_struct {
    int a;
    double b;
    int c; 
};
my_struct x = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

then `( void * )&x == ( void * )&x.a` evaluates to `1`.

Note: the casting is required because the operands have different types and there is no implicit conversion from one type to another.

One more example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    int y[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha 
              << ( ( ( void * )&y == ( void * )y ) && ( ( void * )&y == ( void * )&y[0] ) && ( y == &y[0] ) ) 
              <<'\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
true
```

All three expressions `&y`, `y`, and `&y[0]` have the same value (address). (An array used in an expression with rare exceptions is converted to pointer to its first element.)

Answer (score 1):

The address of two separate declared variables are almost never equal (`==`).

Here, `my_struct x = { 1, 2, 3 };` is declared separately from `int y[] = { 1, 2, 3 };`. When they're declared, they're given their own space in memory to occupy, so they're in two different spaces in memory. Even though the values stored by struct `my_struct x` and array `int y[]` are the same, they're stored in their own memory spaces.

If you want to see the actual memory locations, you can do this with a simple `cout` print statement:

```
cout << "&y[0]: " << &y[0] << endl;
cout << "&x.a: " << &x.a << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

`&y[0]` and `&x.a` are different addresses. If you are trying to check if they are the same, you can write a simple programm. And you will see the result.

```
struct my_struct {
    int a;
    double b;
    int c; 
};

int main()
{

    my_struct x = { 1, 2, 3 }; 
    int y[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::cout << "&y[0] = " << &y[0] << "\n&x.a = " << &x.a << "\n&y[0]==&x.a = " << (&y[0]==&x.a);
}
```

The output is:

```
&y[0] = 0x72261501a440
&x.a = 0x72261501a450
&y[0]==&x.a = 0
```

So we can see different values of &y[0] and &x.a. They are not the same. and also `&y[0]==&x.a = 0` and it means `false`

Answer (score 0):

`&` gives you the address of an object.

`&y` gives you the address of the array `y`.

`&y[0]` gives you the address of the first element in array `y` which is equal to `&y`.

`&x` gives you the address of the struct `x`

`&x.a` gives you the address of the first member of the struct `x` which is equal to `&x`.

Since `x` and `y` are at different locations the addresses differ.

Comment: By: "... which is equal to `&x.a`" you meant: "... which is equal to `&x`".

Comment: And: "... which is equal to `&y`" is incorrect, it's: "... which is equal to `y`".

Comment: @PaulEvans It is correct in the sense that the value is equal. It is incorrect in the sense that the type is not equal. "Equal to `y`" isn't quite correct either, since `y` is an array; not a pointer so the type is still different. `y` does in many contexts decay to pointer to first element, and this decayed pointer is exactly equal to `&y[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` will return memory address (depending on your target platform that is usually 16 to 64 bit number, either representing physical memory address, or virtual logical address mapped to physical memory by OS (on modern OS like linux or MacOS, the user process doesn't see true physical addresses by default)).

So this part of source:

```
my_struct x = { 1, 2, 3 }; 
int y[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

will instantiate both the structure and array in the memory as global variables, i.e. they will have memory addresses like `0x12345678`, etc... and they will not overlap, if size of `my_struct` is for example 20 bytes, and `x` address is 0x1000, the array `y` will be in memory somewhere beyond it (address of `y` is also address of first element, in C/C++ the arrays are zero-cost abstraction, i.e. where the array starts, there's the first element already stored, and the rest of elements follow on consecutive memory addresses).

So your original expression `&y[0] == &x.a` is comparing one (absolute) address of particular element of the array with (absolute) address of structure member, and because they are instantiated in different regions of memory, the addresses will surely differ (as long as the index into array is within bounds) = **false**. You don't even need to check details which addresses precisely are compared.

But for completeness, the `y[0]` is the first element of array `y`, and address of that is identical to `y` itself. If there would be `&y[1]`, that's address of second array element, with type `int` that means the `&y[1]` is equal to `y+1` and/or to `((void*)y) + sizeof(int)` ... in CPU machine code terms, that means if array starts at memory at address 0x2000, and `int` is 64 bits on your target platform, the second element starts at address 0x2008 (+8 bytes (64 bits) away from the start of array).

The `&x.a` is similarly full address where the actual value of member `a` resides in memory, so if the structure instance `x` starts at address 0x1000, the address of `x.a` will be also 0x1000 in this case (again zero cost of abstraction and it's simple struct type, if it would be class-like, having virtual functions, the member `a` would be probably a bit offset after the implicit virtual table pointer which is usually put at beginning of class/struct instance ... but this is implementation/platform specific, i.e. depends how particular compiler implements virtual functions/calls). For example the address of `&x.b` would be then 0x1008 (again I assume 64 bit `int` type, and I assume there's no extra padding applied in the `my_struct`, with different assumptions/conditions the offset of `b` from start of structure may be different than +8).